# Ruby on Rails 3, debian, problem with bundle install and other executables under room

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debian

I have problem with install of rails 3, and that is that under root nothing works considering ruby on rails.
lets say if I do this:

```
~/ruby/ev_rada$ sudo bundle install
sudo: bundle: command not found
~/ruby/ev_rada$
```

But if I find manually i can do this:

```
~/ruby/ev_rada$ sudo /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1195:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

same thing is with gem, but installing gems works (I think ) :)

```
~/ruby/ev_rada$ sudo gem install jquery-rails
sudo: gem: command not found


~/ruby/ev_rada$ sudo /usr/local/rvm/bin/gem-ruby-1.9.2-p290 install jquery-rails
Successfully installed jquery-rails-1.0.13
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for jquery-rails-1.0.13...
Installing RDoc documentation for jquery-rails-1.0.13...
```

Thank you for any help

I think I got latest ruby and rails

```
~/ruby/ev_rada$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using RVM, with which you typically don't `sudo`.  Is there a particular reason you need to use sudo to run bundler?  Do you not have access to the directory?  If you do need sudo with RVM, use `rvmsudo` instead.

Comment: thank you, that explains it :) for some reason I got error not writable when I tried to install one gem, jquery, and I thought I need root to install it